# Removing an item from Local Storage on Chrome Dev Tools no longer gives instant feedback and requires closing and reopening to see result

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

Have been experiencing a strange bug(?) with Chrome Dev Tools, where when I try to remove an item from Application > Local Storage tab, it no longer gives instant feedback (asin, the change is not reflected live). Likewise, when programmatically changes are made to Local Storage.

It requires me to close and reopen Dev Tools for me to see these changes reflected, which is highly inefficient for workflow.

I feel like this is likely not a bug, as I can't find it reported anywhere else online, perhaps a setting toggled by mistake unknown to me. Still, help much appreciated in reacquiring instant feedback. Thanks guys! Screen grab below:

[image]

EDIT: Just tried disabling all my extensions, and still the same problem.

Comment: Definitely a bug. I can't reproduce it here though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be fixed with a reinstall of Chrome.